# Alternative to calling target_link_libraries in subdirectory

Tags: c++, cmake, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

### Case:

I've declared a function `setup_target_for_coverage` in a separate .cmake-script, added to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, which prepares a target (`mylib`) for code coverage analysis. `setup_target_for_coverage` is called from a subdirectory to `mylib` (`mylib_tests`).

**The requirement is that everything that has to do with testing and code coverage, *for this target only*, happens in `mylib/tests` and `setup_target_for_coverage`**, and from `mylib/CMakeLists.txt` we only add the test-subdirectory and *nothing more*. In the end, neither test-specifics or the existence of code coverage is known to `mylib`, it just "blindly" calls `add_subdirectory( tests )`.

### Example:

It looks like this:

mylib:

```
# ./mylib/CMakeLists.txt:

project( mylib )
add_library( mylib main.cpp )
# This is all mylib should be aware of, everything else is hidden
add_subdirectory( tests )
```

mylib_tests:

```
# ./mylib/tests/CMakeLists.txt:

project( mylib_tests )

# ...

include(code-coverage)
setup_target_for_coverage(
    TARGET mylib
    TEST_RUNNER mylib_tests
)
```

code-coverage:

```
# ./cmake/code-coverage.txt:

function(setup_target_for_coverage)
    # Parse arguments...

    # Setting compile flags: Works as expected
    target_compile_options( ${args_TARGET}
        PRIVATE
            -g -O0 --coverage
    )

    # Setting linker flags: THIS FAILS <---------------
    target_link_libraries( ${args_TARGET}
        PRIVATE
            --coverage
    )

    add_custom_target( ${args_TARGET}_coverage}
        # Setup lcov, run "TEST_RUNNER", generate html...
        COMMAND ...
    )

endfunction()
```

In short, it sets up compiler & linker-flags (`--coverage`) and adds a custom target which runs gcov/lcov and genhtml.

### Issue:

The issue is with `target_link_libraries`, which (as documented) is required to occur within the same "directory" where the target was created:

> The named `<target>` must have been created in the current directory by
>   a command such as `add_executable()` or `add_library()` [...]

I thus get the following error:

```
Attempt to add link library "--coverage" to target "mylib" which is not built in this directory.
```

---

I've tried to get around this by using `set_property` directly

```
set_property(
    TARGET ${TARGET} 
    APPEND_STRING PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS "--coverage"
)
```

to no avail. It fails with the following error, even if in same CMakeLists.txt:

```
"undefined reference to `__gcov_merge_add'"
```

---

It works if `target_link_libraries` is moved to `./mylib/CMakeLists.txt`, but this is as mentioned not fulfilling my requirements.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please give a [mcve]? From what you are showing, it's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you give the code of "the setup-function" or at least the `target_link_libraries()` call in question?

Comment: @Florian Definitely! I wrote this with tired eyes last night, and realize it's rather vague... I'll edit it asap.

Comment: Weird. In CMake terminology "current directory" is introduced with `add_subdirectory()` only, it doesn't distinguish case when function is defined in included file. And such use case (calling `target_link_libraries` from the function, defined not in the current directory) works for me with CMake 3.4.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh, my bad! My example lies a little in that `setup_target_for_coverage` is actually run within the `tests` subdirectory..! Reason for this is that I don't know the target-name for the test-target until here (mylib is agnostic to what the test does). I'll fix the example.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Though. solving the "test-target name", if it works by having `setup_target_for_coverage` in `mylib/CMakeLists.txt`, that is a much easier hurdle to overcome...

Comment: Could your requirements be relaxed a little to allow using `include()` instead of `add_subdirectory()`? If so, then this would allow `target_link_libraries()` to be used. The main disadvantage is that inside your `tests` directory, you would have to remember that CMake would be treating the current source directory as `mylib`, not `mylib/tests` (and similar for the corresponding binary directory).

Comment: @CraigScott That would be a viable sacrifice, thanks for the tip! I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning comment into an answer. As you've highlighted, you can only call `target_link_libraries()` on a target defined in the same directory scope (**Edit:** this restriction no longer exists since CMake 3.13). When you call `add_subdirectory()`, you enter a new directory scope and therefore hit the problem you've asked about.

The `include()` command, on the other hand, does not create a new directory scope. This has two immediately relevant effects:

- In the *included* directory's file, you can still call `target_link_libraries()` for a target in the *including* directory's scope.
- The value of `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` doesn't change, so you will likely be wanting to use `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` instead within the included file. Note that there is no equivalent for `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` which also doesn't change.

A typical pattern might be something like this:

*mylib/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_library( mylib main.cpp )
include( tests/CMakeLists.txt )
```

*mylib/tests/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_executable( someTest "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/someTest.cpp" )
# ...
```

Perhaps at least tangentially related, you might also find the ideas in [this article](https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/) to be of interest. It shows how to manage sources and targets across directories, touching on the `add_subdirectory()` versus `include()` discussion along the way.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed a valid alternative, with only minor modifications. One thing that bothers me a little with this approach though is that it pushes the changes upwards, all the way to `mylib`. Personally, I'd rather solve it by a "hack" in `code-coverage.cmake` (something like `set_property`, if it would just work as advertised). This way, the added complexity would be hidden from higher-level entities.
If I can't find a solution like that any time soon, I'll mark this as the answer!

Comment: I went with this solution! It was the (IMO) most clean "work-around" which didn't complicate things too much. See implementation [here](https://github.com/helmesjo/hello-ci/blob/7bde2cd03dcc5b935f3ea01e8ed226aa21e6ad7c/src/mylib/CMakeLists.txt#L74).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `function` by `macro`:

```
macro(setup_target_for_coverage)
  [...]
endmacro()
```

CMake macros are similar to C macros: you can think of it as a text replacement, so that it behaves as if the code was located in the original file.

Comment: Sorry, missed some critical info in my example. See updated question!