# CMake Error: Attempt to add link library to target which is not built in this directory (only when policy CMP0079 is set to NEW)

Tags: c++, cmake, target-link-libraries

I want to link the component "fsm" into my executable (main.cpp). "fsm" is dependent on "taskmap". So I was trying to figure out how to configure cmake to recognise my libraries the correct way, but the configuration always fails with the following errors:

**Errors** (yielded while configuring):

```
[cmake] CMake Error at components/taskmap/CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_link_libraries):
[cmake]   Attempt to add link library "taskmap" to target "sample_project" which is
[cmake]   not built in this directory.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   This is allowed only when policy CMP0079 is set to NEW.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:8 (include)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at components/fsm/CMakeLists.txt:8 (target_link_libraries):
[cmake]   Attempt to add link library "fsm" to target "sample_project" which is not
[cmake]   built in this directory.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   This is allowed only when policy CMP0079 is set to NEW.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
```

**My directory structure:**

```
project
├───CMakeLists.txt
├───components
│   ├───fsm
│   │   ├───fsm.cpp
│   │   ├───CMakeLists.txt
│   │   └───include
│   │       └───fsm.hpp
│   └───taskmap
│       ├───CMakeLists.txt
│       └───include
│           └───taskmap.hpp
└───main
    ├───main.cpp
    └───CMakeLists.txt
```

**CMakeLists.txt** (toplevel):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(sample_project VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(main)
include(components/taskmap/CMakeLists.txt)
include(components/fsm/CMakeLists.txt)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

**main/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_executable(sample_project main.cpp)
```

**components/fsm/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(
    fsm
    fsm.cpp
    include/fsm.h
)

target_include_directories(fsm PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(sample_project PRIVATE fsm)
```

**components/taskmap/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(
    taskmap
    include/taskmap.h
)

set_target_properties(taskmap PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

target_include_directories(taskmap PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(sample_project PRIVATE taskmap)
```

I can't really make a lot out of this error and have done some research:

[CMake: Attempted to add link library to target which is not built in this directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838367/cmake-attempted-to-add-link-library-to-target-which-is-not-built-in-this-direct)

This person tried to target_link_libraries() in the toplevel CMakeLists.txt, even though the executables are added in a subordered CMakeLists.txt. Apparently target_link_libraries() needs to be called from the CMakeLists.txt where the target is specified (except if the directory scope remains the same, see below).

[Alternative to calling target_link_libraries in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811329/alternative-to-calling-target-link-libraries-in-subdirectory)

This person attempted to use target_link_libraries() with the "link to"-target not specified in the same directory as the newly created target (because a new subdirectory scope was entered). I think this is somewhat related to my problem, so I switched to use include() directives instead of add_subdirectory(), **but the error stays the same**.

So nothing helped so far. Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `include(components/taskmap/CMakeLists.txt)` why not `add_subdirectory(components)`? Also why target ancient cmake version?

Comment: @Genjutsu: add_subdirectory() yields the same error. I had it this way first and hoped changing it to include() would make the error go away. About the version idk, I used cmake quick setup to pull this up, but its an ancient version for sure.

Comment: @Genjutsu: having said that, changing cmake version up to 3.20 at least gets rid of the error!

Comment: In line with "Modern CMake" you should ALWAYS use the latest version unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: CMake is not forwards compatible so if you set 3.0.0 as your minimum without actually testing on 3.0.0, it is almost certain to break once the project reaches a certain size. Newer CMake versions will make no attempt to stop you from using features that are not available in earlier versions.